# How to exclude un-wanted records from a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL statement that I need a little bit of help with. I am pulling the data correctly but I just need a some help excluding the records that are not need. If the candidate remaining attempts equal 0 I do not want to pull that record, but as you can see the I am using a subquery to generate the number of remining attempts a candidate may have.

Is there a way to use the remaining_attempts field in the WHERE statement to exclude the un-wanted records?

```
    SELECT (
                SELECT  count(*) AS Number_Attempts_Used
                FROM    candidate_exam_record
                WHERE   candidate_exam_record.idcandidate_eligibilty = candidate_eligibilty.idcandidate_eligibilty
            ) AS remaining_attempts
            , (
                SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) > '0' THEN candidate_exam_record.idcandidate_eligibilty END
                FROM candidate_exam_record
                WHERE candidate_exam_record.idcandidate_eligibilty = candidate_eligibilty.idcandidate_eligibilty) AS EL_ID
    FROM    candidate_eligibilty
            INNER JOIN candidate ON candidate_eligibilty.idcandidate = candidate.idcandidate
            INNER JOIN exam ON candidate_eligibilty.exam_id = exam.exam_id
            INNER JOIN jurisdiction ON exam.jurisdiction_id = jurisdiction.jurisdiction_id
    WHERE   jurisdiction.jurisdiction_id = 'xxxx' 
            AND candidate_eligibilty.eligibility_end_date >= '2013-02-19'
            AND remaining_attempts > '0'
```

Comment: do you need this count (I mean do you need remaining_attempts in your data returned)?

Comment: It is not necessary remaining_attempts to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It's messy but it looks OK to me. Try changing `'0'` to just plain old `0`. You're storing it as an INT I assume, correct?

Comment: there is the rub the remaining_attempts field is not a field in a table it is generated by a sub-subquery.

Comment: Can you see what type of value is actually getting stored in remaining_attempts?